# gpg: decryption failed: No secret key

Tags: macos, gnupg, yubikey

First, I spent an hour trying answers with similar titles so please read this through before flagging this question as a duplicate.

I use a YubiKey to store my PGP private key using its smart card feature.

I confirm the private key works as I can connect to servers using SSH (which triggers `pinentry-mac`).

```
$ cat .gnupg/gpg-agent.conf
enable-ssh-support
default-cache-ttl-ssh 60
max-cache-ttl-ssh 120
default-cache-ttl 60
max-cache-ttl 120
pinentry-program /usr/local/bin/pinentry-mac
```

The `gpg: decryption failed: No secret key` error is thrown when the YubiKey smart card is not unlocked and I run `gpg` commands.

```
$ gpg --decrypt /path/to/file.asc
gpg: encrypted with RSA key, ID redacted
gpg: encrypted with 4096-bit RSA key, ID redacted, created redacted
      redacted
gpg: public key decryption failed: Broken pipe
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
```

When the above error is thrown, connecting to a server using SSH triggers `pinentry-mac`, I then `ctrl+c` and run `gpg --decrypt /path/to/file.asc` and `pinentry-mac` is triggered.

What is going on here? How can I get `gpg --decrypt /path/to/file.asc` to work without having to use `ssh` first?

I am probably missing something!

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading GnuPG from version `2.2.22` to `2.2.23` using `brew upgrade` solved the problem.